# Launcher for windows which is exactly same as Mac OS X?

Tags: windows-7, macos, dock, launcher

Is there any launcher for Windows which is exactly the same as Mac OS X in both feel and features?

Answer (score 0):

[RocketDock](http://rocketdock.com/download) will give you the required functionality. It gives you a launcher similar to Mac OSX.

From their website :

> RocketDock is a smoothly animated, alpha blended application launcher. It provides a nice clean interface to drop shortcuts on for easy access and organization. With each item completely customizable there is no end to what you can add and launch from the dock.
>
> Now with added Taskbar support your minimized windows can appear as icons on the dock. This allows for better productivity and accessibility.

My screenshot:

[image]